# Can a user edit another user

Tags: users, user-groups

So I'm setting up a system with 3 tiers of users.

- Admin
- Officers
- Managers

I want Officers to be able to administer managers. Any of you know if this is doable?

So let's say an Officer could login (**not in the CP**) and view a list of its managers and change let's say, their password...

Any light on this would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you're looking for with some caveats from the front-end of a site.

If officers have the `editUsers` permissions, then they can edit most other things about other users.

The two exceptions are their email address, which requires the `changeUserEmails` permission and the password, which they can't change at all.  The only person that can change the password is the user it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Brad. That's most of what I need. One more question if I may. Do you know if I can display the 'copy password reset url' or 'suspend' function from the front end?

Comment: Craft requires you to be an admin to call those methods on its UsersController. If you want to get around that you'd have to write a plugin that has a controller that removes the restriction, but I'd be very wary of opening that up on the front-end.